# Load a specific UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I'm trying to add two sidebar menus in my app. All is fine except that when I return to the previous view controller (that is in an other UINavigationController with different sidebar), I have the same recent sidebar displaying. I want to open its sidebar instead of the recent sidebar. I'm thinking that if I load its navigation controller I'll have the desired result because the sidebar is related with the navigation controller.
Please take a look at this screenshot to know what I mean:

[image]
Thank you for helping.